# JavaScript Variable in C# Statement in Razor MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, variables, razor

How can I access a JavaScript variable in C# code snippet within a Razor view? Here is an example of what I mean:

```
function mixIt(id) {
    var markup = '<div>' + @Model.Shaker.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ShakerID == id) + '</div>';
    return markup;
}
```

Notice where I am checking the id, that id is a javascript parameter. The code above isn't working, and I don't know how to get it to work. Google searching didn't bring anything useful either.

Comment: You can't. That variable is client side.. and not available when the server is rendering the page. Best you can do is an Ajax request back to the server passing the `id`.

Comment: The Razor is run on the server, and the JavaScript is run in the browser. That is, two different computers. You need to learn a little more about the Client/Server behaviour of the web...

Comment: Thank You. I honestly did not know that. Ha good to know. I'll have to re-think the problem and come up with a different approach for a solution. :)

Comment: I'm a little lost by all the don'ts. some of this is short sighted -- Ciwan you CAN pass a model or complex razor variable to JS using `@html.raw(json.encode(model))`

Comment: @Ciwan, all these esteemed contributors are focusing on the wrong subject. While you don't want to be running linq statements in your JS, if you pre-process them in your controller and pass your computed model along, you CAN use it in your JS. And THAT seems to be your real goal. take it from a fellow noob ;)

Comment: Thanks Dave. Yes my model and all the data I need is already present within the View. I just need to filter through it. No call-back is needed to the server again (I believe). Correct?

Comment: I think you should filter in advance. that may mean sending an extra property in your model. But everyone is right that you cannot filter or run any delegates within your js. that WOULD require AJAX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put you won't be able to, the JavaScript code will be **executed in the browser** where as the C#/Razor will be **executed on the server**. This means that the result of your Razor snippet will be generated before the response is sent down to the browser.